# Find and replace all matching dynamic strings using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, replace, foreach, pattern-matching, replaceall

Here is the body of my html:

```
<body>
    <div>_good morning John... _welcomeText.</div>
    <label> _welcomeText </label>
    <a href="">_good</a>
</body>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
var custom_obj = {};
custom_obj["_welcomeText"] = "Welcome in custom";
custom_obj["_good"] = "Good in custom";

$.each(custom_obj, function(key, value) {
    $('body').text(function(index,text){
        return text.replace(key,value);
    });
});
```

This code works but it only replaces the 1st instance of matched pattern. As I am replacing the `key` which is a dynamic value coming from `foreach` loop, I am not able to use `/key/g` to replace all the instances. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend a text based operation like that

Important, It will be very costly

```
var custom_obj = {};
custom_obj["_welcomeText"] = "Welcome in custom";
custom_obj["_good"] = "Good in custom";

var $contents = $('body *').addBack().contents();
$.each(custom_obj, function (key, value) {
    var regex = new RegExp(key, 'g');
    $contents.each(function () {
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(regex, value);
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9X9MM/)

Comment: I have 1 problem. If there is something like: `<label class="_welcomeText_"> dummy text </label>` then you code does not work. Is there any way to fix it??

Comment: if you have a predefined set of attributes which need to be tested that can be done

Comment: can you tell me how to do it

Comment: OK. I found the solution. `$('.'+key).removeClass(key).addClass(value);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use this syntax to create a regular expression

```
var myRegex = new RegExp(key, 'g');
```